# Create select list that only show specific data based on user ID from JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working on a form that will only show data that is related to the user based on their user ID.

This is the JSON link I'm working with - https://fama.aidan.work/datas/json?id=17

THis is HTML code:

```
    <!-- Select List -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="selectlist_34544">Pilih Lot</label>
    <p class="help-block"></p>
    <select id="selectlist_34544" name="selectlist_34544[]" data-alias="" data-optionsjson="" class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Sila pilih lot berkaitan</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the JQUERY code

```
let dropdown = $('#selectlist_34544');

dropdown.empty();

dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose State/Province</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

const url = '/datas/json?id=17';

// Populate dropdown dengan senarai Lot/Kemudahan
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.value).text(entry.name));
  })
});
```

This is the output. 
[It does show all the data in the JSON file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx59e.png)

However, this is the result that I get.
[It does not pass the value hence the empty section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usbnw.png)

How can I make it pass the value as well so that it wont be empty? ANd How to let it show only data that is related with user's ID (or in the JSON Data it is labelled as assigned_user_id)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be basically OK, as I got it working with other data from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, see below.

The properties you are using do exist in the returned JSON data and they are placed into the right positions in your jQuery expression. However, when I tried to use your URL, I received the message:

> Access to fetch at 'https://fama.aidan.work/datas/json?id=17' from origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

So, check your console: If your calling page is run on a different server from the one you host your JSON data then "CORS" restrictions might be the cause of your problem.

```js
let dropdown = $('#selectlist_34544');

dropdown.empty();
dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose State/Province</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

// Populate dropdown dengan senarai Lot/Kemudahan
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.username).text(entry.name));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="selectlist_34544">Pilih Lot</label>
    <p class="help-block"></p>
    <select id="selectlist_34544" name="selectlist_34544[]" data-alias="" data-optionsjson="" class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Sila pilih lot berkaitan</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I get to display the data from JSON in the select list. But when I submit the form, it doesn't display the value that I select. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you made sure the `<select>` element sits inside a `<form>` element?

Comment: Yes. it is in the <form> element. The problem is that it is the only field that doesn't display value when submitted.